# Specific day number using java Calendar API

Tags: java, date, calendar

How can I get a day number from a given date using Calendar API.

Example :
`02/01/2016` is the first saturday in 2016 (result `1`)
`10/01/2015` is the second saturday in 2015 (result `2`)

I thought I can use the week number

```
int week = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

But it does not work when we have a precedent year of 53 weeks

Example : `09/01/2016` will return `1` when it's the second Saturday of 2016

Comment: Beware that the definition of Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR varies by Locale.

Comment: You have not defined what a week-of-year means to you. Do you mean the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) standard definition (first Thursday of the calendar-year is week # 1 starting on a Monday)? Or do you mean week # 1 has January 1st? Or week # 1 has the first Sunday or some other day-of-week? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with `setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()`

1 - I take the week number as I need it : `int weekNbr = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);`

2 - I set the number of days in first week to 1 : `cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(1);`

3- Week number will now reflect the correct number of the weekend :  `int weekendNbr = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);`